# Transport Stream Standard

Tags: frame, packets, mpeg2-ts, transport-stream

I want to know proper standard for transport streams,Some of my doubts are:

1. If size of PES packet is > 65536 then `pes_packet_length` filed should be zero ?
2. If PES packet size more than 65536 then do we require PES header for over flow packets ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) PES Length should always be 0 for the video stream, and always set to real values for any other stream. 2) no, only video streams are aloud to have packets larger than 65535.

Comment: Yeah but if packet size is more than 65535 then should there be PES header in TS for this overflow packet ??

Comment: What overflow packet? A video PES packet has no limitation on size.

Comment: As per my understanding

1) PES_packet_length = Frame size + PES header(If Frame size < 65535)

               2) If frame size is > 65535 then PES_Packet_Length would be set as 0
so while accommodating extra bytes of frame(Which are > 65535 )do we need PES header in TS ??

Comment: This is resolved..
I have convinced myself after reading iso13818 standard which states that pes_packet_length = 0 if PES packet length > 64Kb.. and there should not be PES Header for overflow packets(As we know PES Header is inserted at the start of new PES packet data in TS file..In this case PES header will be inserted once whole data (>64 KB) is covered in TS packets )..

Answer (score 1):

It depends about the information carried by your PES packet: cf this very good [poster](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cascaderange.org%2Fpresentations%2FDVB_Poster.pdf&ei=8GKyU9ktw6o8xduAiA0&usg=AFQjCNHnYTVlxHCDv4j34KIwlW-ICUAXyw&sig2=Epr3TDLkQ1iG6mnAc-S9Pw&bvm=bv.69837884,d.ZWU) by Tektronix for PES packet format.